# Unable to manage multiple clients (android devices) for a single java server

Tags: java, android, multithreading, client-server

I need my server to keep track of each of it's client's connection. I've been advised to use Threads. So what I'm trying to achieve is to create a Thread for each client, which should run till the client connection exists. But what is happening is that for each message any client sends, a new client connection gets created in the doInBackground() function. So instead of having one single thread for one single client, I'm getting one thread for any client message sent to the server. Can you suggest a method in with which my server would be able to distinguish different messages sent from different clients?

Java Server Code :

```
package com.nss.academyassistserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class AcademyAssistServer {
    public static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static Socket clientSocket;

    static final int PORT = 4444;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT); // Server socket         
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: "+PORT+" \n");
        }
        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port "+PORT);

        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New connection accepted."); // accept the client connection
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
            //new thread for a client               
            new EchoThread(clientSocket).start();
        }
    }
}

class EchoThread extends Thread {

    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String fromClient;
    Socket clientSocket;

    public EchoThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
             System.out.println("I am thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId()); 
            try {
                fromClient = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if ((fromClient == null) || fromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                    System.out.println("You're welcome, bye!");

                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(fromClient);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client Activity Code:

```
    package com.nss.academyassist;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Locale;

    //import statements for client
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    //import statements for client
    import android.os.AsyncTask;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        EditText question;

        //Client sockets
        private Socket client;
        private PrintWriter printwriter;
        private String toTag;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            question = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            Button query = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            query.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    client = new Socket("Server IP Address", 4444);
                    printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                    printwriter.write(toTag); // write the message to output stream

                    printwriter.flush();
                    printwriter.close();
                    client.close(); // closing the connection

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.button2:

                        toTag = question.getText().toString();
                        // Output the result
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toTag, 
                                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //Invoke the execute method of AsynTask, which will run the doInBackground method of SendMessage Class
                        SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                        sendMessageTask.execute();

                    break;
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IP to tell the clients. Use

```
clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
```

You can also keep the client not closed in the android code. For example, you may open the `Socket` in `onCreate` and `close` it in `onDestroy`.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for your problem is in your client code. Using `new Socket(..)` your client will create a new connection each time it sends a tag to the the server. So instead of that you could create a single connection that is reused:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    /* .. your other variables .. */

    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* .. no change here .. */
    }

    public void onStart()
    {
        if(this.client != null)
        {
            try {
                client = new Socket("Server IP Address", 4444);
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClose()
    {
        this.printwriter.close();
        this.printwriter = null;
        this.client.close();
        this.client = null;
    }

    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                printwriter.write(toTag); // write the message to output stream
                printwriter.write("\n"); // delimiter
                printwriter.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button2:

                    toTag = question.getText().toString();
                    // Output the result
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toTag, 
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //Invoke the execute method of AsynTask, which will run the doInBackground method of SendMessage Class
                    SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                    sendMessageTask.execute();

                break;
        }

    }
}
```

In addition to that you should append some delimiter to your tag/message in order for the server to be able to distinguish the content from different messages.

Since you are using [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) which seperates lines

> by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a
>   carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed

I added a line that appends a line feed after the tag in the example above for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, using new Socket(..) will create a new connection each time the client sends a tag to the the server. What you suggested, gives an error since we cannot do any network operations on the main UI thread in android. That's the reason I had done it in AsynTask.

Comment: In that case I think you will need 3 AsyncTasks: 1 for connecting in onCreate(), 1 for sending messages, 1 for disconnecting in onClose()

Comment: That's exactly what I did later on. Thank you. :)